# nivo slider - issues in images transition

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have an issue with the nivo slider. The transition in FF is showing very slowly, and the navigation buttons are not showing at all.
Please refer to the link:
http://dev.getchkd.com/index.php

Comment: Consult the documentation of nivo. http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/

Comment: To add - its mostly likely something within you config for it. Post that up.

Comment: Are you sure you have the images for the buttons in the correct folder? This question doesn't have too much information, neither says what have you tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

To fast transition in slider you have to change below line in js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js file

animSpeed:500,

increase this value and check, i hope its done